# drupal_set_title not working in template.php preprocess_page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm attempting to override a page title using the Drupal 7 drupal_set_title function.

```
function newtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) { 

    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    if ($path == 'apply-for-a-brochure') {
        drupal_set_title('Request a brochure today');
        $vars['title'] = 'Request a brochure today';
    }

}
```

If I put an exit in the if statement to check the path it outputs correctly so the code is running. However drupal_set_title isn't taking effect.

I have read other answers suggesting this should work in the preprocess_page function. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I can see nothing obviously wrong with your code. Things can get screwy sometimes when more than 1 module or theme try to set the title. Some themes do funky stuff with setting titles. Set your site to debug mode so it outputs comments in the source, you may then be able to find out where it is being set... maybe

Answer (score 0):

Clear your drupal cache after add code in template file.